# label inconsitently redefined NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

i have been following a YouTube tutorial on how to make an operating system, as well as experimenting with writing assembly code my self. I use NASM to turn my assembly files into executable binaries, and use qemu to run them.

-=-=-=-=-=

**boot.asm**

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov [BOOT_DISK], dl

mov bp, 0x7c00
mov sp, bp

mov bx, tst
call pst
call readisk

%include 'print.asm'
%include 'diskread.asm'

jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa
```

-=-=-=-=-=

**diskread.asm**

```
PROGRAM_SPAVE equ 0x7e00

readisk:
    mov bx, PROGRAM_SPACE
    mov al, 4
    mov dl, [BOOT_DISK]
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02

    int 0x13
    
    jc diskreadfail

    ret

BOOT_DISK:
    db 0

diskreaderr:
    db 'Failed to read the disk!',0

diskreadfail:
    mov dx, diskreaderr
    %include 'print.asm'
    call printstring
    
    jmp $
```

-=-=-=-=-=

**print.asm**

```
printstring:    
    mov ah, 0x0e
    .looper:
    cmp [bx], byte 0
    je .exit
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp .looper
    .exit:
    ret
teststring:
    db 'Hello, World!',0
```

I get a few errors while trying to convert.
I am not sure how i *'define the same label more than once to different values.'*

*source: [fossies.org/linux/nasm/asm/labels.c](https://fossies.org/linux/nasm/asm/labels.c) line 523*

```
print.asm:1: error: label `printstring' inconsistently redefined
print.asm:1: note: label `printstring' originally defined here
print.asm:3: error: label `printstring.looper' inconsistently redefined
print.asm:3: note: label `printstring.looper' originally defined here
print.asm:10: error: label `printstring.exite' inconsistently redefined
print.asm:10: note: label `printstring.exite' originally defined here
print.asm:12: error: label `teststring' inconsistently redefined
print.asm:12: note: label `teststring' originally defined here
```

Comment: Looks like you included the `print.asm` twice. Notice the errors say the original and the redefinition are in the same place. Maybe it's also included from `diskread.asm` that you did not show.

Comment: @Jester It is included in `diskread.asm` so i can print the 'Failed to read the disk!' error to the console if it happens. Also i'll include `diskread.asm` to the original post again.

Comment: Do not include source files in other source files. Assemble them separately, then link the object files together.

Comment: You don't need to include it in `diskread.asm`, and definitely not in the place you have it, in the middle of code path. If you delete it from there, it should work.

Comment: `diskread.asm:4: error: symbol `PROGRAM_SPACE' undefined

diskread.asm:17: error: label `BOOT_DISK' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]

diskread.asm:20: error: label `diskreaderr' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]

diskread.asm:23: error: label `diskreadfail' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]` oh boy

Comment: Do you mean `PROGRAM_SPAVE` or `PROGRAM_SPACE`?

Comment: Ok, yeah, that fixed it! Thank you so much  TonyK and Jester!